# Select Top 10 Elements from each value in a list

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I am using Reportbuilder and I reached to a point where I need to select top 10 elemnts from each value in a list.Is there any way around this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure SQL, depending on the RDBMS.  In MS SQL Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` in a subquery, then limit the main query to the first 10 rows of each group.

```
SELECT <FieldList>
FROM (
    SELECT <FieldList>,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <Group Fields> ORDER BY <Order of records fields>) AS RowNum
    FROM <Tables>
    ) T
WHERE T.RowNum <= 10
```